# ¿Por qué no itera el for?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo este código HTML donde a través de la función quiero iterar unos cards contiendo los datos del json, pero no entiendo por qué no está iterando el índice en el ciclo for:

```js
function displayCard() {
  var cardHtml = '';
  for (var [index, chronicle] of chronicles.entries()) {
    var libro = chronicle['osisID'];
    var verso = chronicle['verse'][index]['osisID'];
    var w = chronicle['verse'][index]['w'][0]['termino'];


    cardHtml += `<div class="card text-left">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="holder.js/100px180/" alt="">
                <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Libro: ${libro}</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Versículo: ${verso}</p>
                <p class="card-text">Lema: ${w}</p>
                <div class="lema"></div>

                </div>
            </div>`
    document.querySelector('.cardhb').innerHTML = cardHtml;

  }
  /* function displayLemma() {
      var lemahtml='';
      for(var j=0; j<=chronicle['verse'][index]['w'].length; j++){
          var lema=chronicle['verse'][index]['w'][j]['lemma'];
          console.log(chronicle['verse'][index]['w'][j]['lemma']);
          lemahtml+= `<p class="card-text lema">Lema: ${lema}</p>`
          document.querySelector('.lema').innerHTML = lemahtml;
          }
          return lemahtml;
      } */
}
let chronicles = [{
  "osisID": "1Chr.1",
  "verse": [{
      "osisID": "1Chr.1.1",
      "w": [{
          "lemma": "121",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13xeN",
          "termino": "אָדָ֥ם"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "8352",
          "@n": "0.0",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13Nvk",
          "termino": "שֵׁ֖ת"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "583",
          "@n": "0",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13TyA",
          "termino": "אֱנֽוֹשׁ"
        }
      ],
      "seg": {
        "@type": "x-sof-pasuq",
        "termino": "׃"
      }
    },
    {
      "osisID": "1Chr.1.2",
      "w": [{
          "lemma": "7018",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13vuQ",
          "termino": "קֵינָ֥ן"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "4111",
          "@n": "0.0",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13TSc",
          "termino": "מַהֲלַלְאֵ֖ל"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "3382",
          "@n": "0",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13k5P",
          "termino": "יָֽרֶד"
        }
      ],
      "seg": {
        "@type": "x-sof-pasuq",
        "termino": "׃"
      }
    },
    {
      "osisID": "1Chr.1.3",
      "w": [{
          "lemma": "2585",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13nPh",
          "termino": "חֲנ֥וֹךְ"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "4968",
          "@n": "0.0",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13LN3",
          "termino": "מְתוּשֶׁ֖לַח"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "3929",
          "@n": "0",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13Qzf",
          "termino": "לָֽמֶךְ"
        }
      ],
      "seg": {
        "@type": "x-sof-pasuq",
        "termino": "׃"
      }
    },
    {
      "osisID": "1Chr.1.4",
      "w": [{
          "lemma": "5146",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13aPd",
          "termino": "נֹ֥חַ"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "8035",
          "@n": "0.0",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13eYX",
          "termino": "שֵׁ֖ם"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "2526",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13C5U",
          "termino": "חָ֥ם"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "c/3315",
          "@n": "0",
          "@morph": "HC/Np",
          "@id": "13qNN",
          "termino": "וָ/יָֽפֶת"
        }
      ],
      "seg": [{
          "@type": "x-sof-pasuq",
          "termino": "׃"
        },
        {
          "@type": "x-samekh",
          "termino": "ס"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "osisID": "1Chr.1.5",
      "w": [{
          "lemma": "1121 a",
          "@morph": "HNcmpc",
          "@id": "13EVS",
          "termino": "בְּנֵ֣י"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "3315",
          "@n": "1.2",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13PB6",
          "termino": "יֶ֔פֶת"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "1586",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "1337c",
          "termino": "גֹּ֣מֶר"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "c/4031",
          "@n": "1.1",
          "@morph": "HC/Np",
          "@id": "13x9c",
          "termino": "וּ/מָג֔וֹג"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "c/4074",
          "@n": "1.0",
          "@morph": "HC/Np",
          "@id": "13yNB",
          "termino": "וּ/מָדַ֖י"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "c/3120",
          "@morph": "HC/Np",
          "@id": "1329t",
          "termino": "וְ/יָוָ֣ן"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "c/8422",
          "@n": "1",
          "@morph": "HC/Np",
          "@id": "13KZG",
          "termino": "וְ/תֻבָ֑ל"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "c/4902",
          "@n": "0.0",
          "@morph": "HC/Np",
          "@id": "13TZE",
          "termino": "וּ/מֶ֖שֶׁךְ"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "c/8494",
          "@n": "0",
          "@morph": "HC/Np",
          "@id": "13thY",
          "termino": "וְ/תִירָֽס"
        }
      ],
      "seg": [{
          "@type": "x-sof-pasuq",
          "termino": "׃"
        },
        {
          "@type": "x-samekh",
          "termino": "ס"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "osisID": "1Chr.1.6",
      "w": [{
          "lemma": "c/1121 a",
          "@n": "1.0",
          "@morph": "HC/Ncmpc",
          "@id": "13JM7",
          "termino": "וּ/בְנֵ֖י"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "1586",
          "@n": "1",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13fpo",
          "termino": "גֹּ֑מֶר"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "813",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13W26",
          "termino": "אַשְׁכֲּנַ֥ז"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "c/7384 a",
          "@n": "0.0",
          "@morph": "HC/Np",
          "@id": "13yw4",
          "termino": "וְ/דִיפַ֖ת"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "c/8425",
          "@n": "0",
          "@morph": "HC/Np",
          "@id": "13jbg",
          "termino": "וְ/תוֹגַרְמָֽה"
        }
      ],
      "seg": {
        "@type": "x-sof-pasuq",
        "termino": "׃"
      }
    },
  ]
}]
```

```html
<section>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="marca" onclick="displayCard()">Términos</button>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="cardhb">
    <div class="card text-left">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="holder.js/100px180/" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Libro</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Body</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No entiendo exactamente que es lo que dices que no itera, porque enrealidad el codigo como lo tienes **SI** que itera entre libros, lo que pasa es que solo itera una vez, porque según la estructura que tienes **SOLO HAY UN LIBRO**.

Entonces yo supuse que lo que realmente querias era poder extraer el libro y sus versiculos en ese formato, por lo tanto me di a la tarea de realizarlo.

Tu confusion se debe al formato en si que contiene tu informacion, pues enrealidad tienes `UN` solo objeto dentro de un array:

```
var chronicles = [{"osisID": "1Chr.1", ...}];    //UN SOLO OBJ = UN SOLO LIBRO
```

Y esto de por si no hace falta decir que se traduce a **UNA** sola iteracion, pues segun tu estructura **NO** tienes mas libros.

Ahora bien, si nos vamos a la parte de `verses` en tu obj:

```
let chronicles = [{
  "osisID": "1Chr.1",
  "verse": [{
      "osisID": "1Chr.1.1",
      "w": [{
          "lemma": "121",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13xeN",
          "termino": "אָדָ֥ם"
        },
```

Este contiene un arreglo con mucha mas informacion dentro, informacion la cual sospecho es la cual querias que se mostrara, por lo cual lo que enrealidad deberias haber hecho es haber iterado este sub arreglo tambien para agregar esta informacion, quedando entonces que tendrias que utilizar **no 1, si no 2 ciclos**, uno dentro de otro, esto con el fin de asegurar que si en un futuro agregas como tal **otro libro** y no un **verso** al `JSON` este otro libro tambien despliegue su informacion de versos correspondiente, la cual puede llegar a ser tambien un poco mas extensa.

Tiene que ser un ciclo dentro de otro porque el primero itera los `libros`:

```
 //Libro                    //Libro                    //Libro
[{"osisID": "libro1", ...}, {"osisID": "libro2", ...}, {"osisID": "libro3", ...}]
```

Y el segundo itera los **versos del libro**:

```
let chronicles = [{
  "osisID": "1Chr.1",
  "verse": [{                 //1 verso
      "osisID": "1Chr.1.1",
      "w": [{
          "lemma": "121",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13xeN",
          "termino": "אָדָ֥ם"
        },
   },
   {                         //Otro verso
      "osisID": "1Chr.1.1",
      "w": [{
          "lemma": "121",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13xeN",
          "termino": "אָדָ֥ם"
        },
   },
   ...                      //Mas versos
   ...
   ...
  ]
...
...
```

Quedando entonces asi:

```js
function displayCard() {
  var cardHtml = '';
  
  chronicles.forEach((chronicle, index)=> {
    chronicle['verse'].forEach((subverse)=> {
      const lib = subverse['osisID'];
      const verse = lib;
      const ww = subverse['w'][0]['termino'];
      
      cardHtml += 
      `<div class="card text-left">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="holder.js/100px180/" alt="">
          <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">Libro: ${lib}</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Versículo: ${verse}</p>
          <p class="card-text">Lema: ${ww}</p>
          <div class="lema"></div>

          </div>
      </div>`;
    });
    
    document.querySelector('.cardhb').innerHTML = cardHtml;
    
  });
 
  /* function displayLemma() {
      var lemahtml='';
      for(var j=0; j<=chronicle['verse'][index]['w'].length; j++){
          var lema=chronicle['verse'][index]['w'][j]['lemma'];
          console.log(chronicle['verse'][index]['w'][j]['lemma']);
          lemahtml+= `<p class="card-text lema">Lema: ${lema}</p>`
          document.querySelector('.lema').innerHTML = lemahtml;
          }
          return lemahtml;
      } */
}
let chronicles = [{
  "osisID": "1Chr.1",
  "verse": [{
      "osisID": "1Chr.1.1",
      "w": [{
          "lemma": "121",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13xeN",
          "termino": "אָדָ֥ם"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "8352",
          "@n": "0.0",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13Nvk",
          "termino": "שֵׁ֖ת"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "583",
          "@n": "0",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13TyA",
          "termino": "אֱנֽוֹשׁ"
        }
      ],
      "seg": {
        "@type": "x-sof-pasuq",
        "termino": "׃"
      }
    },
    {
      "osisID": "1Chr.1.2",
      "w": [{
          "lemma": "7018",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13vuQ",
          "termino": "קֵינָ֥ן"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "4111",
          "@n": "0.0",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13TSc",
          "termino": "מַהֲלַלְאֵ֖ל"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "3382",
          "@n": "0",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13k5P",
          "termino": "יָֽרֶד"
        }
      ],
      "seg": {
        "@type": "x-sof-pasuq",
        "termino": "׃"
      }
    },
    {
      "osisID": "1Chr.1.3",
      "w": [{
          "lemma": "2585",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13nPh",
          "termino": "חֲנ֥וֹךְ"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "4968",
          "@n": "0.0",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13LN3",
          "termino": "מְתוּשֶׁ֖לַח"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "3929",
          "@n": "0",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13Qzf",
          "termino": "לָֽמֶךְ"
        }
      ],
      "seg": {
        "@type": "x-sof-pasuq",
        "termino": "׃"
      }
    },
    {
      "osisID": "1Chr.1.4",
      "w": [{
          "lemma": "5146",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13aPd",
          "termino": "נֹ֥חַ"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "8035",
          "@n": "0.0",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13eYX",
          "termino": "שֵׁ֖ם"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "2526",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13C5U",
          "termino": "חָ֥ם"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "c/3315",
          "@n": "0",
          "@morph": "HC/Np",
          "@id": "13qNN",
          "termino": "וָ/יָֽפֶת"
        }
      ],
      "seg": [{
          "@type": "x-sof-pasuq",
          "termino": "׃"
        },
        {
          "@type": "x-samekh",
          "termino": "ס"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "osisID": "1Chr.1.5",
      "w": [{
          "lemma": "1121 a",
          "@morph": "HNcmpc",
          "@id": "13EVS",
          "termino": "בְּנֵ֣י"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "3315",
          "@n": "1.2",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13PB6",
          "termino": "יֶ֔פֶת"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "1586",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "1337c",
          "termino": "גֹּ֣מֶר"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "c/4031",
          "@n": "1.1",
          "@morph": "HC/Np",
          "@id": "13x9c",
          "termino": "וּ/מָג֔וֹג"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "c/4074",
          "@n": "1.0",
          "@morph": "HC/Np",
          "@id": "13yNB",
          "termino": "וּ/מָדַ֖י"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "c/3120",
          "@morph": "HC/Np",
          "@id": "1329t",
          "termino": "וְ/יָוָ֣ן"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "c/8422",
          "@n": "1",
          "@morph": "HC/Np",
          "@id": "13KZG",
          "termino": "וְ/תֻבָ֑ל"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "c/4902",
          "@n": "0.0",
          "@morph": "HC/Np",
          "@id": "13TZE",
          "termino": "וּ/מֶ֖שֶׁךְ"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "c/8494",
          "@n": "0",
          "@morph": "HC/Np",
          "@id": "13thY",
          "termino": "וְ/תִירָֽס"
        }
      ],
      "seg": [{
          "@type": "x-sof-pasuq",
          "termino": "׃"
        },
        {
          "@type": "x-samekh",
          "termino": "ס"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "osisID": "1Chr.1.6",
      "w": [{
          "lemma": "c/1121 a",
          "@n": "1.0",
          "@morph": "HC/Ncmpc",
          "@id": "13JM7",
          "termino": "וּ/בְנֵ֖י"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "1586",
          "@n": "1",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13fpo",
          "termino": "גֹּ֑מֶר"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "813",
          "@morph": "HNp",
          "@id": "13W26",
          "termino": "אַשְׁכֲּנַ֥ז"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "c/7384 a",
          "@n": "0.0",
          "@morph": "HC/Np",
          "@id": "13yw4",
          "termino": "וְ/דִיפַ֖ת"
        },
        {
          "lemma": "c/8425",
          "@n": "0",
          "@morph": "HC/Np",
          "@id": "13jbg",
          "termino": "וְ/תוֹגַרְמָֽה"
        }
      ],
      "seg": {
        "@type": "x-sof-pasuq",
        "termino": "׃"
      }
    },
  ]
}]
```

```html
<section>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="marca" onclick="displayCard()">Términos</button>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="cardhb">
    <div class="card text-left">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="holder.js/100px180/" alt="">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Libro</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Body</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**NOTA**: es posible realizarlo como lo estabas haciendo con `.entries`, por lo que podrias adaptar mi respuesta a tu respuesta usando `.entries` pero en este ejemplo lo he modificado y simplificado un poco mas para usar mas bien 2 `forEach`, quiza no sea lo mas optimo en cuestiones de velocidad, sin embargo para una cantidad de datos tan pequenas con el `forEach` nos basta y nos sobra.

**NOTA 2**: La estructura con la que estas conformando tus libros (si la construiste tu), debes mejorarla o readaptarla, pues enrealidad como vemos se ha generado esta pequena confusion y hay datos que ni se usan segun tu estructura, deberias replantear tu formato.

Comment: Muchsímas gracias! Agradezco te hayas tomado el tiempo para responder. Gracias por tus Notas. En cuanto a la Nota 2, ese json fue producto de una conversión que hice de XML a JSON, ha unos datos que viste que no usé pero voy a implementar, como también hay otros datos que no usaré, por eso seguiré tu recomendación de mejorarla.